# Geolocation give me a Error when i change pages

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an application with Ionic 4 + Angular 8, I'm facing an issue that I don't understand very well.

I have two events on my home page to get my location, on my ngOnInit I have

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.iniMap();
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.iniWatchingMap();
    }, 2000);
  }
```

I have two functions one to initialize a map and another to start a subscribe event when the user changes his location.

```
async iniMap() {
this.globalLoading = await this.loadingController.create({
  message: 'Carregando Localização',
});
this.globalLoading.present();
this.globalMap = tt.map({
  key: 'my-key',
  container: 'map',
  style: 'tomtom://vector/1/basic-main',
  center: [-53.2, -10.3333333],
  zoom: 16,
});
this.globalMap.addControl(new tt.FullscreenControl());
this.globalMap.addControl(new tt.NavigationControl());
this.globalMarker = new tt.Marker()
.setLngLat([-53.2, -10.3333333])
.addTo(this.globalMap);
this.globalMap.on('load', () => {
  this.renderer.removeClass(this.mapElement, 'hide-map');
  this.renderer.addClass(this.mapElement, 'visible');
  this.mapLoaded = true;
  this.globalLoading.dismiss();
});
```

}

And the other one is my watching function

```
watchPositionUser() {
    const watchOptions = {
      frequency : 3000,
      timeout : 10000,
      enableHighAccuracy: true // may cause errors if true
    };
    this.watchUser = this.geolocation.watchPosition(watchOptions);
    this.watchUser.subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.lat = data.coords.latitude;
      this.long = data.coords.longitude;
      // const points = [[-104.98485, 39.73845], [-118.24334, 34.05224], [-122.42017, 37.78008]];
      this.globalMap.jumpTo({center: [this.long, this.lat]});
      this.globalMarker
      .setLngLat([this.long, this.lat])
      .addTo(this.globalMap);
     }, error => {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.mapElement, 'hide-map');
      this.mapError = true;
      console.log('Error getting location', error);
      this.globalLoading.dismiss();
     });
  }
```

This is working fine when I don't change my page, but when I return to this page after move to another, I getting this error

**Error getting location PositionError {code: 3, message: "Timeout expired"}**

I know that is the timeout but if I don't put a Timeout he takes hours, I don't know why.

Another thing my location is very wrong it is normal in ionic? or it is wrong because I'm testing on the web but if I go to a mobile phone it will be correct?

Here is where the new error appears when I change pages

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.watchUser.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: 1). have you tried in on `ionViewWillEnter()`?
2). Yes on Web Location can be very different from Mobile.

Comment: It occurs the same thing, only work if load for the first time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing is that you need to [unsubscribe when you subscribe](https://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/).

This means you need to keep a class-level reference to the subscription so later on you can remove it.

For your code this would look something like:

```
import { OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { ISubscription } from "rxjs/Subscription";

// class definition needs it like
export class EventListPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

// in the class
private watchSubscription: ISubscription;

iniWatchingMap() {

    // ... snip ...
    this.watchSubscription = watch.subscribe((data: any) => {
      // ... snip ...
     }, error => {
       console.log(error);
     });
  }

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.watchSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

You are also going to need to research the Ionic Page Lifecyle:

[Ionic Page Life Cycle - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle)

Which will give you some options for when you set this up so that the page unsubscribes and also subscribes each time.  I think this will be `ionViewWillEnter` but you will need to do some research yourself to see what works in your scenario.

I think this should be enough for you to make progress.

## updated

This is where you are going wrong with trying to apply my example:

```
  // HERE
  private watchSubscription: any;
  // HERE

  watchPositionUser() {
    const watchOptions = {
      frequency : 3000,
      timeout : 10000,
      enableHighAccuracy: true // may cause errors if true
    };
    this.watchUser = this.geolocation.watchPosition(watchOptions);
    // HERE
    this.watchSubscription = this.watchUser.subscribe((data: any) => {
    // HERE
      this.lat = data.coords.latitude;
      this.long = data.coords.longitude;
      // const points = [[-104.98485, 39.73845], [-118.24334, 34.05224], [-122.42017, 37.78008]];
      this.globalMap.jumpTo({center: [this.long, this.lat]});
      this.globalMarker
      .setLngLat([this.long, this.lat])
      .addTo(this.globalMap);
     }, error => {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.mapElement, 'hide-map');
      this.mapError = true;
      console.log('Error getting location', error);
      this.globalLoading.dismiss();
     });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // HERE
    this.watchSubscription.unsubscribe();
    // HERE
  }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late, i do this exacly like u say, i'm unsubscribe() my observable but is giving me this :

Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.watchUser.unsubscribe is not a function
TypeError: this.watchUser.unsubscribe is not a function, i update my code

Comment: Look at my code again. `watchUser.subscribe()` returns the subscription, which you save to a variable and later run `.unsubscribe` on. You are trying to run it on the actual `watchUser`.